# shape 2 complex GROUP BY / PARTITION BY queries into 1 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I was trying to solve a task with just 1 query using `GROUP BY`, but ended up having a complex solution using `WITH` clause - so I have 2 queries combined. But I suspect I tend to over-engineer it.

Say, we have 3 tables:

(see the whole SQL for the tables' layout under section *schema* below)

- authors
- subjects
- books

For example, the task reads

> find authors who have written books on more than 2 subjects

During my research I have come up with complex, over-engineered 2 solutions:

**solution 1** - using `PARTITION BY` clause work out the row number

```
WITH temp1 AS 
(
    SELECT author_id, subject_id, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY author_id) as rn
    FROM books
    GROUP BY author_id, subject_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT author_id FROM temp1 WHERE rn > 2
;
```

**solution 2** - combining 2 queries containing `GROUP BY` clause

```
WITH temp1 AS 
(
    SELECT author_id, subject_id
    FROM books
    GROUP BY author_id, subject_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT author_id, COUNT(*) FROM temp1
GROUP BY author_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
;
```

**Is there any way to solve such a task with just 1 query?**

---

### Schema

The SQL below applies to PostgreSQL

```
CREATE SEQUENCE authors_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE authors
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('authors_id_seq'::regclass),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_authors PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE subjects_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE subjects
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('subjects_id_seq'::regclass),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_subjects PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE books_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE books
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('books_id_seq'::regclass),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    popularity int NOT NULL,
    author_id bigint NOT NULL,
    subject_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_books PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_books_authors_author_id FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
        REFERENCES authors (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_books_subjects_subject_id FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)
        REFERENCES subjects (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

seed data:

```
INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES 
('John Doe'),
('Friedrich Nietzsche');
INSERT INTO subjects (name) VALUES 
('anatomy'),
('geography'),
('nature');
INSERT INTO books (name, popularity, author_id, subject_id) VALUES
('body', 5, 1, 1),
('earth', 10, 1, 2),
('ocean', 9, 1, 2),
('animals', 9, 1, 3),
('birds', 7, 2, 3);
```

Comment: `SELECT author_id
    FROM books
    GROUP BY author_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subject_id) > 1`

Comment: No, it only return authors with multiple subjects due to COUNT DISTINCT

Comment: @dnoeth authors who have books on just 1 subject are also pulled by your query. this task is rather complex, isn't it? :)

Comment: @AlexHerman https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=cc371d45680b62eff9a213a693ceccd4 check this it works

Comment: No, it's not complex at all, in fact in it's a very basic question. And if it's only for checking *more than one* this might use less resources: `having min(subject_id) <> max(subject_id)`

Comment: @dnoeth your query appears to be right, I forgot I messed up with the DB by adding new book records, will double check everything now

Comment: @dnoeth all verified, confirming again your SQL is 100% correct. thank you very much indeed! I must catch up on SQL immediately :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just you need distinct subject count based on author_id

```
SELECT author_id FROM books 
GROUP BY author_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subject_id) > 2
```